# Receiving unexpected logging messages after changed config

Tags: python, logging

Previously I used this logging pattern

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler("logs.log", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

And my log file had these messages:

```
2019-08-21 11:08:08,271 - INFO - Started
2019-08-21 11:08:08,271 - INFO - Connecting to Google Sheets...
2019-08-21 11:08:11,857 - INFO - Successfuly connected to Google Sheet
2019-08-21 11:08:11,869 - ERROR - Not found: 'TG'
2019-08-21 11:08:11,869 - DEBUG - Getting values from Sheets...
2019-08-21 11:08:12,452 - DEBUG - Got new event row: "Flex - Flex"
2019-08-21 11:08:12,453 - DEBUG - Done. Values: 
...
```

It looks ugly and I changed it to this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
   level = logging.DEBUG,
   format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
   filename = 'logs.log', filemode = 'w'
 )
log = logging.getLogger()
```

Now my log file looks like that

```
2019-08-21 11:14:02,374 - INFO - Started
2019-08-21 11:14:02,374 - INFO - Connecting to Google Sheets...
2019-08-21 11:14:02,406 - DEBUG - [b'eyJ0eX...jcifQ', b'eyJ...NvbSJ9', b'f7BQ...dE2w']
2019-08-21 11:14:02,407 - INFO - Refreshing access_token
2019-08-21 11:14:03,448 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com:443
2019-08-21 11:14:04,447 - DEBUG - https://www.googleapis.com:443 "GET /drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27&pageSize=1000&supportsTeamDrives=True&includeTeamDriveItems=True HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2019-08-21 11:14:04,450 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sheets.googleapis.com:443
2019-08-21 11:14:05,782 - DEBUG - https://sheets.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v4/spreadsheets/1q6...cTI?includeGridData=false HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2019-08-21 11:14:05,899 - INFO - Successfuly connected to Google Sheet
2019-08-21 11:14:05,901 - ERROR - Not found: 'TG'
2019-08-21 11:14:05,902 - DEBUG - Getting values from Sheets...
2019-08-21 11:14:06,426 - DEBUG - https://sheets.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v4/spreadsheets/1q6...cTI/values/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%821 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2019-08-21 11:14:06,543 - DEBUG - Got new event row: xxx
2019-08-21 11:14:06,544 - DEBUG - Done. Values: xxx
2019-08-21 11:14:06,544 - DEBUG - Getting line...
2019-08-21 11:14:06,550 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.site.com:443
2019-08-21 11:14:07,521 - DEBUG - https://api.site.com:443 "GET /v1/fix...?Id=33 HTTP/1.1" 200 6739
```

I receiving some requests debug logs that I didn't use in my code

How to turn it off?
I found that is because of the requests module

Comment: They probably come from some library you use in your application.

Comment: In my opinion you changed the basic config of logging and the `request` module also uses it and you get the `DEBUG` messages from it. Perhaps you can identify the  location of message if you use in format the `%(module)s` or `%(filename)s`

Comment: What module do you use to connect?

Comment: @CristiFati
I use `requests` module" 
Recently updated my question with additional info

Comment: @milanbalazs

You are right. I turned on `module` and `filename` and found
`crypt , crypt.py` and `connectionpool , connectionpool.py` references

Comment: Is it possible to turn them off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for all the log messages from the requests module is because of the below piece of code,

```
logging.basicConfig(
   level = logging.DEBUG   # This sets the root logger to DEBUG
 )
```

`logging.basicConfig` changes the logger configuration of the root logger present in your program

Since you've used `requests` module here, `requests` uses `urllib3` which prints those debug messages.

#### Fix:

You can use your first logger initialisation code to configure your logger else, you can also use the below code,

```
logging.basicConfig(
   format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
   filename = 'logs.log', filemode = 'w'
 )
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)   # Here you are changing the level of your logger alone
```

Comment: Actually, there's only one root logger in your process and `basicConfig` only affects that single root logger. All the other loggers, instantiated during the import of `requests` (and that's a whole bunch: `'urllib3.util.retry', 'urllib3.util', 'urllib3', 'urllib3.connection', 'urllib3.response', 'urllib3.connectionpool', 'urllib3.poolmanager', 'requests'`) are "normal" named loggers. All of them are set to propagate to their ancestor(s). With root being the ultimate ancestor and now set to DEBUG, it logs all the messages it silently dropped before when it defaulted to WARNING.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. In this case you don't change the basic config of logging module. You can config only your instance of `logging.getLogger`. If you use this implementation, it shouldn't have effect to other modules. Furthermore, you can handle the console and file separately so this logger can be more configurable.

**Code:**

```
import logging

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler("logs.log", "w", encoding="utf-8")
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
c_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
f_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.warning("This is a warning")
logger.error("This is an error")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python test.py 
2019-08-21 08:55:10,579 - WARNING - This is a warning
2019-08-21 08:55:10,580 - ERROR - This is an error
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @noufel13's answer, the reason for the additional log messages showing up is that you set the root logger's level to DEBUG and add a handler to it.

By default, importing `logging` instantiates a `RootLogger` object with the level WARNING and no handlers attached.

Importing `requests` instantiates a bunch of library loggers, in particular 
`urllib3.util.retry`, `urllib3.util`, `urllib3`, `urllib3.connection`, `urllib3.response`, `urllib3.connectionpool`, `urllib3.poolmanager` and `requests`.
This is done so that deveolpers using these libraries can easily enable debug output to test and troubleshoot their code, or just have logging output without modifying 3rd party code, just by configuring the root logger accordingly.

All these loggers are created with default values, the relevant being level NOTSET, propagate True and disabled False.

- [Level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) NOTSET (emphasis mine):

> [...] causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or **delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger**

- [propagate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) True:

> [...] events logged to this logger will be passed to the handlers of higher level (ancestor) loggers [...] 
>  The constructor sets this attribute to True

- disabled False:

disabled is an undocumented [attribute of the `Logger` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1404)

These loggers *always* exist when you import `requests` in your program. Also, they *always* emit their log messages.
These messsages are not visible by default because all of these loggers only have a [`NullHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2149) attached ...

> This handler does nothing. It's intended to be used to avoid the
>       "No handlers could be found for logger XXX" one-off warning. This is
>       important for library code, which may contain code to log events. If a user
>       of the library does not configure logging, the one-off warning might be
>       produced; to avoid this, the library developer simply needs to instantiate
>       a NullHandler and add it to the top-level logger of the library module or
>       package.

... and because their ultimate ancestor, the root logger, also comes without any handlers and is set to level WARNING per default.

`basicConfig` *only* affects the root logger. The way you use it, a specific `Formatter` is created and attached to a newly instantiated `FileHandler` that, in turn, is attached to the root logger. Also, the root logger's level is set to DEBUG.

Now, all the messages from the `requests` and `urllib3` loggers ending up at the root logger after traversing the hierarchy, are logged to the file handled by the root's `FileHandler`.

**How to stop that**

As per your original recipe, and as outlined by @milanbalazs, continue to create and configure dedicated loggers for your intended pupose and leave the root logger alone. 
You state, that you find programmatical configuration rather ugly; I somewhat agree.

The [`logging.config`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html) module offers various ways for you to configure your logging.
For example, you could use [`dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) and provide the configuration via a dictionary that you could potentially import from another, dedicated module.

The following configures a logger named *test* the same way your `basicConfig()` approach does for the root logger:

```
import logging.config

cfg_dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "filename": "logs.log",
            "mode": "w",
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "test": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["file"],
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(cfg_dict)
log = logging.getLogger("test")
```

The `logging.config` module futher supports configuration files via [`fileConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) and a [socket listener](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.listen) for configuration data in the suitable formats for dict and file configuration.

If you'd rather configure and use the root logger, you can either disable all "unwanted" loggers or instruct them not to propagate.

```
import logging
import requests

for logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.values():
    logger.propagate = False
    # -- OR --
    logger.disabled = True

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    filename='logs.log',
    filemode='w'
)

log = logging.getLogger()
```

*Note: Both, the `Manager`'s `loggerDict` and the `Logger`'s `disabled` attributes are undocumented. While they are not explicitly marked as an internal implementation detail via Python's convention (i.e. leading underscore name), I would hesitate to consider them part of the official `logging` API and thus expect them to be potential subject to change.*